# LibGDX: Draw a pie chart?

Tags: libgdx, 3d

I'm new to LibGDX, my goal is to render a 3D pie chart, my idea is to draw a Cylinder and somehow define slices that can have different material and transformations.

I can render a cylinder already but I'm not sure how to do the slicing part.